# Excel update PLOT

Tags: excel, plot, dynamic

I'm working on Excel to create a dashboard, so I have the Sheet Dashboard where I can't choose what I want to display (which companies, range lenght, ...). All the parameters are used to create a filtered table on another sheet.

This filtered table is used to create a plot on the Dashboard Sheet (so this plot is dynamic with the parameters). Everything work BUT I don't know why it takes 20 seconds to update the plot (it vanishes then appears) when you change the parameters and I don't know why but when I go to another sheet then go back to the Dashboard sheet the plot is updated directly.

The filtered table is directly updated with the parameters so that's not the issue.

Do you guys have any idea how to fix it?

Many thanks,

Arnaud

I've tried to let the chart on the sheet of the filtered data but it does not change the problem.

Comment: Do you use code to create the charts or just formula?  Pretty hard to tell why it's slow without knowing how the chart is created.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook No I don't use code, I just use the created array to plot the chart. But now it works, I've changed the layout of the plot and it seems to be fixed. Magic...